# Search by dynamic attribute in embedded object using Repository interface

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring-data-mongodb repositories against a collection that contains documents like this:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5411619148e28887be66c02b"), "userId" : { "name" : "something", "alias":"asdasdfasfd" }}
```

and some more fields that are not relevant to the question. The embedded userId object might have only name, only alias or both. I would like to have a single method in the Repository to search by name or alias depending on an input parameter. I haven't found a way of doing it just with the automatic query creation based on the name, so I tried with the @Query annotation, like this:

```
@Query(value="{'userId.?1': ?2}")
List<User> findUser(String type, String id);
```

but the type is interpolated into the query with surrounding quotes, and so the query doesn't work. Is there a way to do this without resorting to having two methods: findByUserIdName and findByUserIdAlias, or a custom implementation?